Flutter Tree View allow for dragging and dropping children into other children nodes
I have a Flutter app built using the Stacked cli, I'm trying to customize my tree view which will allow for the following:

Can drag a child node to the left which will then make it a parent
Can drag child node into another child node

I have point 1 working as expected, however, I can't get the code to work for dragging a child node into another child node.
Here is a breakdown of my code
TreeNode.dart
class TreeNode {
  String id;
  String title;
  List<TreeNode> children;

  TreeNode({required this.id, required this.title, this.children = const []});

  TreeNode copyWith({String? id, String? title, List<TreeNode>? children}) {
    return TreeNode(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      title: title ?? this.title,
      children: children ?? List.from(this.children),
    );
  }
}

Here is my ViewModel:
import 'package:fancy_tree_view/models/tree_node.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';

class FancyTreeViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
   List<TreeNode> _nodes = [
    TreeNode(id: '1', title: 'Root 1', children: [
      TreeNode(id: '1.1', title: 'Child 1.1'),
      TreeNode(id: '1.2', title: 'Child 1.2'),
    ]),
    TreeNode(id: '2', title: 'Root 2', children: [
      TreeNode(id: '2.1', title: 'Child 2.1'),
    ]),
  ];

  List<TreeNode> get nodes => _nodes;

  TreeNode? findParent(TreeNode node, List<TreeNode> nodes) {
    for (var n in nodes) {
      if (n.children.contains(node)) {
        return n;
      }
      var parent = findParent(node, n.children);
      if (parent != null) {
        return parent;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  void moveNode(TreeNode node, TreeNode? newParent) {
    var currentParent = findParent(node, _nodes);
    if (currentParent == newParent) {
      // Node is being dropped on the same parent, do nothing
      return;
    }

    if (newParent != null) {
      // Remove node from its current position
      _nodes = _removeNode(node, _nodes);
      // Add node to the new parent
      newParent = newParent.copyWith(children: List.from(newParent.children)..add(node));
      _updateNode(newParent, _nodes);
    } else {
      // Remove node from its current position
      _nodes = _removeNode(node, _nodes);
      // Add node to the root level
      _nodes.add(node);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<TreeNode> _removeNode(TreeNode node, List<TreeNode> nodes) {
    return nodes.map((n) {
      if (n.id == node.id) {
        return null;
      } else if (n.children.isNotEmpty) {
        return n.copyWith(children: _removeNode(node, n.children));
      }
      return n;
    }).where((n) => n != null).toList().cast<TreeNode>();
  }

  void _updateNode(TreeNode updatedNode, List<TreeNode> nodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      if (nodes[i].id == updatedNode.id) {
        nodes[i] = updatedNode;
        return;
      } else if (nodes[i].children.isNotEmpty) {
        _updateNode(updatedNode, nodes[i].children);
      }
    }
  }
}

And here is my View:
import 'package:fancy_tree_view/models/tree_node.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';

import 'fancy_tree_viewmodel.dart';

class FancyTreeView extends StackedView<FancyTreeViewModel> {
  const FancyTreeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget builder(
    BuildContext context,
    FancyTreeViewModel viewModel,
    Widget? child,
  ) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Fancy Tree View'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      body:  Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  DragTarget<TreeNode>(
                    onWillAccept: (draggedNode) => true,
                    onAccept: (draggedNode) => viewModel.moveNode(draggedNode, null),
                    builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                      return Container(
                        width: 50,
                        color: candidateData.isNotEmpty ? Colors.grey[300] : Colors.transparent,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text("<", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      children: _buildTreeNodes(viewModel.nodes, viewModel),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildTreeNodes(List<TreeNode> nodes, FancyTreeViewModel model) {
       return nodes.map((node) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                DragTarget<TreeNode>(
                  onWillAccept: (draggedNode) => draggedNode != node,
                  onAccept: (draggedNode) => model.moveNode(draggedNode, node),
                  builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                    return Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      color: candidateData.isNotEmpty ? Colors.grey[300] : Colors.transparent,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(">", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: DragTarget<TreeNode>(
                    onWillAccept: (draggedNode) => draggedNode != node,
                    onAccept: (draggedNode) => model.moveNode(draggedNode, node),
                    builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                      return LongPressDraggable<TreeNode>(
                        data: node,
                        axis: Axis.horizontal,
                        feedback: Material(
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(node.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(node.title),
                        ),
                        childWhenDragging: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(node.title),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            if (node.children.isNotEmpty)
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: _buildTreeNodes(node.children, model),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  FancyTreeViewModel viewModelBuilder(
    BuildContext context,
  ) =>
      FancyTreeViewModel();
}

My outcome would be to allow for a user to drag a node to the left which results in that node becoming a parent, then being able to drag child nodes into other child nodes.
Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

you can use flutter_fancy_tree_view package as it comes with Rudimentary Drag And Drop support
